# Big O Notation, Why do we ignore everything inside the log?

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

Okay, so I understand implicitly why we might write `f(n) = log 3n = O(log n)` but I don't really understand why lets say `f(n) = log 3n^2 = O(log n)`. Then what am I suppose to do with `f(n) = log n!` does this also just equal O(log n)?

Or do I need to write it out explicitly like with `f(n) = 2^(2n^3 + log_2 n) = O (2^(2n^3 + log_2 n))` as none of the parts could be removed and still get the same runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the properties of logarithms:
$$\log 3 n^2 = \log 3 + \log n^2 = \log 3 + 2 \log n = O(\log n)$$
and, using $n! \le n^n$ for $n \ge 1$:
$$
\log n! \le \log n^n = n \log n = O(n \log n).
$$
This latter bound is asymptotically tight since $n! \ge \left( \frac{n}{3} \right)^{n/3}$:
$$
\log n! \ge \log \left( \frac{n}{3} \right)^{n/3} = \frac{n \log n}{3} - \frac{n \log 3}{3} = \Omega(n \log n).
$$

Comment: Actually n! >= (n/3)^(2n/3), because there are (2n/3) factors each larger than n/3.

Comment: The above argument is not true if n is not divisible by $3$ and I did not want to deal with rounding (since the result is asymptotically the same).